# I want to reload my page x seconds after a button is clicked

Tags: javascript

So i want my page to reload an amount of seconds after the button is clicked. Right now it reloads every 5 seconds automatically. But if i put the timeout function in the addEvenlistener then it errors. What can i do to solve it?

```
button.addEventListener(
  'click',
  () =>
    (cover.style.visibility = 'hidden') && (button.style.visibility = 'hidden'),
);

setTimeout(function () {
  window.location.reload();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: "if i put the timeout function in the addEvenlistener then it errors"

What error do you see?

Comment: it just says "unexpected token", i think i put it on the wrong place, but have no idea where exact i have to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, this should work. Are you sure you didn't forget the curly braces in the click callback?

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  cover.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  button.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.reload();
  }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write it inside the EventListener as @Jonas mentioned. And also you can have that timeout value to be dynamic as well

```js
var timeoutValue = 5000
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  cover.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  button.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.reload();
  }, timeoutValue);
});
```

Comment: Whats the use that it would be dynamic?

Comment: incase where you want that timeout value to come from some api call